# Initiate a re-render on a component when data from context changes

Tags: reactjs

In my UserAuthContext, I have the following return

```
<userAuthContext.Provider value={{ user, authenticatedUser, logIn, signUp, logOut }}>
  {children}
</userAuthContext.Provider>
```

How I get authenticatedUser:

```
const authenticatedUser = new User();
const { updateUserData } = authenticatedUserr;

useEffect(() => {
    const getUserData = async () => {
      const docSnap = await getDoc(doc(db, "registeredUsers", user.uid));
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        const userData = docSnap.data();
        const mappedUserData = {
          userUsername: "George",
          userEmail: userData.userEmail,
          userDateOfBirth: userData.userDateOfBirth,
          userUid: userData.userUid,
          userVerified: userData.userVerified,
          userIsSeller: userData.userIsSeller,
          userRewardLevel: userData.userRewardLevel,
        };  
        updateUserData(mappedUserData);
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    };
    if ((user) && (user.uid)) {
      getUserData();
    }

}, [user]);
```

In my component, I retreive the data like this:

```
const { user, authenticatedUser, logOut } = useUserAuth();
```

and use it like this:

```
<h1> {authenticatedUser&& authenticatedUser.userState && authenticatedUser.userState.userUsername} </h1>
```

When I print the "authenticatedUser" in my component, the data is available. Unfortunately, the data is available after my component is fully rendered.

I already tried different things, like wrap it in a useEffect, but it has no effect:

Edit 2 - It works now, I had to change the state change in my Context, not in the Component:

```
const authenticatedUserr = new User();
const { updateUserData } = authenticatedUserr;
const [test, setTest] = useState({});  <- NOW IT WORKS WITH THIS

useEffect(() => {
    const getUserData = async () => {
      const docSnap = await getDoc(doc(db, "registeredUsers", user.uid));
      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        const userData = docSnap.data();
        const mappedUserData = {
          userUsername: "George",
          userEmail: userData.userEmail,
          userDateOfBirth: userData.userDateOfBirth,
          userUid: userData.userUid,
          userVerified: userData.userVerified,
          userIsSeller: userData.userIsSeller,
          userRewardLevel: userData.userRewardLevel,
        };  
        updateUserData(mappedUserData);
        setTest(authenticatedUserr) <- NOW IT WORKS WITH THIS
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    };
    if ((user) && (user.uid)) {
      getUserData();
    }

}, [user]);
```

How can I initiate a re-render, after "authenicatedUser" from my context has changed?

Comment: The way to cause a rerender in react is to set state, so make `authenticatedUser` be a state. When you set that state to a new value the provider rerenders, and thus any consumers rerender too.

Comment: Sorry, I have missread your answer. I fixed it by changing the setState in my context, not in my component. NOW it works! Thank you so much. I had heache from my problem

Comment: paste the full component, not just the effect